# IndexError: list index out of range python

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I'm sure it must be a silly mistake but I tried and can't figure it out by myself.
I have a CSV file with the format *id,name,date*time,terminal,status*. I'm trying to create a list of dictionaries (**registros**), where the key:value are each one of the csv's fields.
I use `.split(',')` for doing so, and also `.split('*')` for the date*time field (**fechaHora**), as I need them in different variables. Everything works fine until I try to access the time (**fechaHora[1]**), it gives me the *IndexError*. If i print the whole list I can see how the `.split('*')` works perfectly, and if I print out length **`print(len(fechaHora))`** I get it (len=2), so don't know where my error is.
Put the example code below, any help is appreciated.

```python
"""Registros en archivo son de la forma
1,,Monday0901*085345,1,I"""
archivoOriginal = open('registros.csv', 'r')
registros = []
for linea in archivoOriginal:
    categorias = linea.split(',')
    idEmpl = categorias[0]
    nombre = categorias[1]
    fechaHora  = categorias[2].split('*')
    fecha = fechaHora[0]
    hora = fechaHora[1] #:::this line gives me the error!!
    terminal = categorias[3]
    estado  = categorias[4]
    #registros.append({"id":idEmpl, "fecha":fecha, "hora":hora, "estado":estado})
    registros.append({"id":idEmpl, "fecha":fechaHora, "estado":estado})
print (registros)
archivoOriginal.close()
```

Here is some of the output when I print out **registros**, as you can see, *fecha(fechaHora)* is a list with two items

```
{'fecha': ['Monday0901', '132215'], 'id': '1', 'estado': '0\n'}, {'fecha': ['Monday0901', '132330'], 'id': '2', 'estado': '0\n'}, {'fecha': ['Monday0901', '135328'], 'id': '2', 'estado': '0\n'},
```

I'm using python 3.4.1

Comment: Surely one of your lines does not contain the `*` in the third column?  It would help if you print the line at the top of the loop and then paste for us the line that it prints when (just before) it fails.

Comment: Do `try: hora = fechaHora[1]` and `exceptIndexError: print(fechaHora, len(fechaHora), line, sep='\n')`

Comment: As we say in spanish "el que sabe, sabe" (the one who knows, definitely knows). The title of the third field of my .csv document didn't have the `*`, thanks for the comment @JohnZwinck ! For testing purpouses I just changed the title from `Fecha/Hora` to `Fecha*Hora`. 
PS: Not sure how to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for linea in archivoOriginal:
```

with

```
for N, linea in enumerate(archivoOriginal):
```

Run you file with either `python -i filename` or open in an Idle editor and hit F5.  After the traceback, there will be an interactive prompt `>>>`.  Enter `print(N, linea)` to see the number and line where you have a problem.